# How to check if result from array_intersect is empty?

Tags: php

I am trying to check the result of an array_intersect as a regular array but it always returns true even if the array is empty.

```
      $lecturedayssplit1 = preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/", "TF");
      $lecturedayssplit2 = preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/", "MTh");
      $lectolec=array_intersect($lecturedayssplit1,$lecturedayssplit2);
        if (count($lectolec) > 0) {
            echo "Yeah!!!";
            print_r($lectolec);
        } else {
            echo "Nooo!";
            print_r($lectolec);
        }
```

`$lectolec` in the problem shouldn't return a count greater than 0 because there is no intersection between the two arrays. I also tried `if (empty($lectolec))` but  it also didn't work. Hopefully someone can help out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a "zero-width positive lookahead" `(?=[A-Z])` regex, it is matching an empty sequence in the beginning of each test. Therefore, `array_intersect` matches that empty sequence in both.

You can use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to ignore those empty results.

```
$lecturedayssplit1 = preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/", "TF", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$lecturedayssplit2 = preg_split("/(?=[A-Z])/", "MTh", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: hello, thanks will try this out. what does -1 stand for?

Comment: the `-1` says that there is no limit in the max number of results.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I got it. I changed the conditional to `if (count($lectolec) > 1)` because it always has at least one count even if the array is empty

Comment: Sorry, but this is nonsense! If an array is empty, then `count(array)` is `0`.

Comment: Yeah haha clearly, sorry about this. Simon pointed out that there is indeed an intersection that I'm not aware of